# I got mysqli error 1064 but i don't know why

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I want to post this data from android client and i tested it with postman and status code was 200. But i have a mysqli error and it's:

Error:

> ((1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=' at line 1)

i don't know what is my codes problem and SELECT part works correctly

```
<?php


$id = $_POST['id'];
$isLiked = $_POST['isLiked'];


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
$query = "SELECT likes FROM posts WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);



$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$likes = $array['likes'];

if ($isLiked == true) {

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE posts SET likes=" . $likes++ . " WHERE id=$id";

} else {

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE posts SET likes=" . $likes-- . " WHERE id=$id";

}


if (!$connection->query($updateQuery)) {
    echo "query failed: (" . $connection->errno . ") " . $connection->error;
}

mysqli_query($connection, $updateQuery);
if (!$connection->query($updateQuery)) {
    echo "query failed: (" . $connection->errno . ") " . $connection->error; // It returns that 1064 error
}

mysqli_query($connection, $updateQuery);
```

Comment: Your `$id` can be empty

Comment: Your Code is vulnerable to sql-injections. Have a look at [`prepared statements`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Never put values directly into SQL strings. Use parameters/prepared statements. Also you don’t need to calculate it in code. It only causes issues if multiple events happen at the same time.

Comment: Read: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Also read: https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see 3 possible mistakes.

First mistake, the **$id can be empty**.

And 2nd mistake can be $likes++ need be **++$likes**, because you doesn't sum it with ++ after of the variable, im referring too to **--$likes**.

The 3rd mistake is your code is vulnerable to MySQL injection, i recommend make a **prepared statement**.

Link to **prepared statement** example and explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Their code is vulnerable to sql injection -- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @robbyoconnor changed

Comment: @deoncagadoes you're not linking to anything: https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @robbyoconnor now its better ?

Comment: @deoncagadoes, no w3schools is a horrible resource.